# EM algorithm and random effects

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, expectation-maximization

I am trying to learn how to fit random effects/mixed effects models. I read on [this article](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/introduction-to-generalized-linear-mixed-models/#issues) that quasi-likelihood, numerical integration and MCMC are the most common methods.

My question is:

- can we fit these models using Expectation-Maximization?

They seem to be related to the same problem (maximum marginal likelihood), but I have never heard of these together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all missing data problems (random effect models) can be fit using the EM algorithm.  It is a good exercise to derive the components for the EM algorithm for a normal mixed model